# Template is not working in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new in AngularJS. I have used this code to get the number for counter animation.

```
<p  counter value="autoStartVar" to="100">{{ autoStartVar | number:0 }}</p>
```

But i want to put dynamic number instead of "100". Means like bellow

```
<p  counter value="autoStartVar" to={{currentlead.Avg_Monthly_Bill__c}} | {{monthlyusage}}>{{ autoStartVar | number:0 }}</p>
```

It is not working. How can it possible ? Is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: What is counter? A directive?

Comment: don't interpolate values (don't use `{{ }}`) when passing variables to directives.  just pass the variable.  i.e. `to="currentlead.Avg_Monthly_Bill__c"`.  Also, you were missing quotes as well.

Comment: Thank you claies, can you give the answer for this why it is like this and one more thing is i have another number with decimal. But it is not working. forecast.Year_1_Annual_Bill__c.toFixed(2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass a variable in directive, pass without {{}}, if you need to pass value like string use the {{}}. The modified code given below:

```
<p  counter value="autoStartVar" to="currentlead.Avg_Monthly_Bill__c">{{ autoStartVar | number:0 }}</p>
```